# how to display a number that is a char

Tags: c++, char, ascii

I have a multi-dimensional array of chars that I want to display.  one of the dimensions has numbers in it (0, 1, 2, etc.).  When I go to display the array, I get the ascii results.  I realize the char output works as defined (char + number = ascii) but I was looking to specifically show the number.

Ex.

```
char a = 3;

cout << a; // gives me #
```

I want to display 3.  I have tried casting to an int:  `cout << (int)a;`

I have tried casting inside the array `myArray[(int)a];`

Neither of those have seemed to work, and you can't convert `const char` to a `string` so I'm kinda lost.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 3 has another meaning if you cast to char. If you want 3, do `a = '3'`

Comment: `cout << (int)a;` should have worked, if I understand you correctly.  What exactly happened when you did that? Can you show a self-contained test case, please?

Comment: @Zack I am not in front of the computer with the code and won't be until later today.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have

```
char a = 3;
```

Now you can:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(a);
```

or

```
int b = a;
std::cout << b;
```

or

```
printf("%d",a);
```

The output of any of the above would be

```
3
```

Comment: @PlasmaHH If you don't want anyone to be able to read your code.

Comment: @SingerOTheFall: Its unary plus, and for all arithmetic operations, integral types are at least promoted to int before applying the arithmetics.